# Why I can't create a UDT with name profiles?

Tags: cassandra

```
CREATE TYPE IF NOT EXISTS myks.profiles (
    "field" text
);
```

It gives me the below exception when I try to create a UDT with name profiles `com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.SyntaxError: line 1:17 no viable alternative at input 'profiles' (CREATE TYPE myks.[profiles]...)`

Comment: what version of Cassandra?

Comment: I'm using DataStax Enterprise Server 5.1.7 and Apache Cassandra 3.11.1.2130

Answer (score 3):

Update: it looks like a bug. I suggest to use word **profile** instead...

Original answer:

Keyspaces in Cassandra are created with [`CREATE KEYSPACE` command](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlCreateKeyspace.html), and you're trying to create a new user-defined type instead.  This error is returned because the keyspace `myks` is not yet defined.

In your case full command will be:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS profiles WITH replication = 
   {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'your_dc': 'rep_factor'};
```

you need to substitute the name of your datacenter(s) instead of `your_dc`, and adjust `rep_factor` to match number of nodes.

But for beginning I suggest to watch at least DS201 course on [DatStax Academy](https://academy.datastax.com/) - it should give your overview of basic operations, etc.

Comment: Extremely sorry. There is a typo in the question. It's not keyspace I'm trying to create a UDT with name profiles. myks is my keyspace which is already created

Comment: Anyway - check if keyspace is created correctly - replication, etc.

Comment: My Keyspace is created with this `{
  "class" : "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy",
  "replication_factor" : "1"
}`

Comment: yes may be its a bug. I have created couple of UDT's but failed creating a UDT with name `profiles`. UDT with name `profile` was success.

Comment: `profiles` is keyword for DSE Search, so it maybe clash with it (not 100% sure), although it works for example, for tables...